# SharePoint Online posting an item to a list with element field

Tags: javascript, json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint list with a number of field. I'm using JavaScript to post to the list by doing the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://my.domain.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: data,//Example WORKING JSON{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.TestListItem' }, 'title': 'Test' },
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Success");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("Failure");
    }
});
```

And that is working wonderfully. The issue is that one of my fields, when I use Postman is like so:

```
<d:Sst_Country_mc m:type="Collection(Edm.String)">
   <d:element>Netherlands</d:element>
</d:Sst_Country_mc>
```

So I thought my Json would be like so:

```
{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Data.SST_x0020_Requests_x0020_StagingListItem"
  },
  "Title": "Andrew Test 4",
  "Sst_Customer_Name_st": "Customer",
  "Sst_Business_Category_sc": "Finance and Insurance",
  "Sst_Country_mc": {
    "element": "Spain"
  },
  "Sst_Actual_Request_mt": "",
  "Sst_E_Model_1_st": "MODEL",
  "Sst_E_Hardware_Qty_1_ni": "1",
  "Sst_Deadline_Validate_d": "01/01/2017",
  "Sst_Office_sc": "B UK"
}
```

But this fails with the following error:

> A collection was found without the 'results' property. In OData, each collection must be represented as a JSON object with a property 'results'.

It's not to do with how I'm posting, as when I remove the field, it works, but I need this field populated for a workflow that kicks off on item creation.

How should my Json be formatted to handle the country field? I tried a basic `"Sst_Country_mc":"Spain"` also and that didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `Sst_Country_mc` is a choice field set to allow multiple selections...

In your REST data payload, that field should be in the format of an **object** with a property called **"results"** which should contain an **array** of string values.

```
"Sst_Country_mc": {
    "results":["Spain","Netherlands"]
}
```

Your final data payload might look something like this:

```
{
    "__metadata": {"type": "SP.Data.SST_x0020_Requests_x0020_StagingListItem"},
    "Title":"Andrew Test 4",
    "Sst_Customer_Name_st":"Customer",
    "Sst_Business_Category_sc":"Finance and Insurance",
    "Sst_Country_mc": {
        "results":["Spain","Netherlands"]
    },
    "Sst_Actual_Request_mt":"",
    "Sst_E_Model_1_st":"MODEL",
    "Sst_E_Hardware_Qty_1_ni":"1",
    "Sst_Deadline_Validate_d":"01/01/2017",
    "Sst_Office_sc":"B UK"
}
```